# Truffle Console: Sending Ether to a contract using fallback function

Tags: ether, fallback-function, truffle-console

I have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract  Victim {
   address owner;
   constructor() public{  
      owner = msg.sender;
   }
  
   function deposit()  payable public {}
}
```

If I wanted to send Ether to the above contract using deposit function, I used to wrote:

```
acc1 = accounts[1]

options = { from: acc1, to : victim.address, value: web3.utils.toWei('99', 'ether')}
```

and then:

```
contractObj.deposit.sendTransaction(options)
```

Now suppose that I have a fallback function instead of deposit function, how can I send Ether to the contract? Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer works beautifully:
truffle(development)> const myContract = await Victim.deployed()
truffle(development)> myContract.sendTransaction({from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("1", 'ether')})

I would like to add to it by saying that if "myContract.sendTransaction" is replaced with "web3.eth.sendTransaction", the eth is not transferred to myContract unless myContract.address is in the "to" property; although the funds are always withdrawn from accounts[1].

web3.eth.sendTransaction can be run from within the same truffle console environment, and it's results easily followed in ganache.

Comment: Can you format the code to improve its readability?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Truffle docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#sending-ether-triggering-the-fallback-function):

> You can trigger the fallback function by sending a transaction to this
> function:
>
> ```
> const result = instance.sendTransaction({...});
> ```
>
> This is promisified like all available contract instance functions,
> and has the same API as `web3.eth.sendTransaction` without the callback.
> The `to` value will be automatically filled in for you.

First, add the fallback function to your contract:

```
function () external payable {}
```

Then in your truffle console run the following commands:

```
truffle(development)> const myContract = await Victim.deployed()
truffle(development)> myContract.sendTransaction({from: accounts[1], value: web3.utils.toWei("1", 'ether')})
```

You will see something like this:

```
{
  tx: '0x22b2161c3d2df23fa3665e17818f18e0ec1aa85e8651b58173eb98c5129422e3',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x22b2161c3d2df23fa3665e17818f18e0ec1aa85e8651b58173eb98c5129422e3',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0xfad483d89d468baf3f11169b0c7f2ac8d98eb6c0e9ce8d446447997e90fc0813',
    blockNumber: 5,
    from: '0xed3e91355793f627432d8033df7d9f410a00d77e',
    to: '0x7f17856af4f34e7de93683642fc6e2d4bff44f3a',
    gasUsed: 21040,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 21040,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    status: true,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    rawLogs: []
  },
  logs: []
}
```